# Can I subscribe to the edits for an individual answer?

Tags: discussion, questions

Is there a way to subscribe to the subscription feed for an individual answer so that you are notified if someone edits it?

Comment: Paolo Bergentino?

Answer (score 3):

Well, if it your question or answer you will be notified in the Recent Activity page (Envelope) under Edits to your posts.

Otherwise, I don't believe there is a way to receive updates about edits to a post.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. But this would be a *great* use for [Wave integration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172/what-kind-of-google-wave-integration-would-you-like)...

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this?

Sounds like someone needs to be reminded of the golden rule:

> Other people can edit my stuff?!
>
> Like Wikipedia, this site is
>   collaboratively edited. If you are not
>   comfortable with the idea of your
>   posts being edited by other trusted
>   users, this may not be the site for
>   you.

Comment: *That's* the golden rule?  You mean it's not at all related to golden showers?  Now I just feel violated.

Comment: @Pesto: I am sorry you feel violated. I tried to warn you about what happens at Fogcreek during the interview process...

Answer (score 0):

They should show the edits in the Responses Envelope page.

Edit: I found that they do have a Quantity and link in the Responses Envelope page for Edits to your own posts.  Now we just need the subscription capability for other posts.